# new AjaxUpload start by some other button

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I'm using the `valums.com/ajax-upload` plugin. The problem is that it starts uploading as soon as I select a file, I want to start the upload by clicking some other button, so user can change values if they want to.

HTML:

```
<div id="upload" ><span>Upload File<span></div>
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
<span id="status" ></span><ul id="files" ></ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var btnUpload = $('#upload');
    var status = $('#status');
    new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
        action: 'upload-file.php',
        name: 'uploadfile',  
        autoSubmit: false,
        onSubmit: function(file, ext){
            // if (! (ext && /^(pdf)$/.test(ext))){ 
            if (!(ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|pdf)$/.test(ext))) { 
                // extension is not allowed 
                status.text('Only JPG, PNG or GIF files are allowed');
                return false;
            }

            upload.setData({'example_key': 'value'});
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response) {
            //On completion clear the status
            status.text('');

            //Add uploaded file to list
            if (response === "success") {
                $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="./uploads/'+file+'" alt="" /><br />'+file).addClass('success');
            } 
            else {
                $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('error');
            }
        }
    });

    $("#submit").click(); ////dont know how to do it.
});
```

Comment: What is 'the AjaxUpload plugin'? Quite a few can be found from google. I'm guessing http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ ??

Comment: can u tell me how did u validate this ..i means on sumbit its should alert or show message ...please upload file ..

Answer (score 3):

```
uploader = new AjaxUpload(...);
uploader.submit();
```